# No 300 ms delay click on EaselJS shapes

Tags: javascript, event-handling, createjs

So I am trying to create a game using CreateJS, which includes TweenJS and EaselJS.

Here is a sample of the code I am using-

```
    var shape = new createjs.Shape();
    shape.graphics.beginFill("Red").drawRoundRect(50, 50, 300, 200, 20);
```

This just creates the shape. I want mobile devices to be able to click on it easily without any kind of delay.
I have tried [fastclick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/), but it only works on DOM Elements and not EaselJS shapes.

I used the `shape.on('click')` method to produce a simple click. I tried to do `shape.on('touch')`, but it didn't work out.

I am using an application called PhoneGap, which converts HTML webpages into apps.

I have tried to look for many resources to help me with this problem, but I have not found yet. Can someone please help me find out what exactly I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some more code? How are you binding the event-listener(s) to the createjs-Shape? You can bind them using easeljs "on" method (http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/EventDispatcher.html#method_on). There shouldn't be a delay on touch devices.

```
 shape.on("click", function(event) {
 // to something
 });
```

Keep in mind that you can use the CSS-Property `touch-action` and set it to `manipulation` to get rid of the touch-delay in newer browser (> Safari 9.1):
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH10-SW8

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited my question. I did the same thing that you have shown. However, I am not sure that the `touch-action` property can have any effect on the delay on the PhoneGap browser. However, I will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple actually-

I can't believe I hadn't seen this before. The `shape.on("click")` wasn't working because it wasn't enabled in the CreateJS Touch API.

You just have to include one line of code here-

```
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
```

This can bind the events to enable them in touch. They are defined here- 
http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Touch.html